# Persistent tmux session with shared socket

Tags: linux, tmux

I would like there to always be a tmux session on a socket in /tmp/shared with a session of 0. That way I can always attach to the session via SSH:

```
ssh user@www.example.com -t tmux -S /tmp/shared attach-session -t 0
```

I want it to be shareable with other users and be able to recreate itself if a less knowledgeable, or careless user uses exit instead of [ctrl] + d when leaving the session.

I'm sure it's possible to do this in a cron, but I don't know that there isn't a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a socket file owned by selected users mutual group and using a session name would be better then using session number.

```
/// Create session
tmux -S /tmp/shareds new -s sharedsession
/// Change ownership to group
chgrp mutual_group_name /tmp/shareds
/// Run this in other user or ssh session to attach yourself
tmux -S /tmp/shareds attach -t sharedsession
```

A few ways to check session status:

1. you can create a cron but it will delay creation of sharedsession because of minimum 1 minute rule.
2. init.d script to run it as a service, similar to [this one](https://gist.github.com/jdavis/8164358)
3. you can install supervisord and use it to auto daemonize your shared session creation script

Last year i used [tmate](http://tmate.io/) running as a daemon. You can create a tmate server and attached sessions from different machines with using daemonized tmate in them. But i can not guarantee security for this cause i used them in a private network.

Answer (score 0):

The following attaches to session 0 or creates a new session:

`tmux new-session -t 0 || tmux`

I don't think that you can create sessions with a specific session number, so you might want to consider using a session name.  However a custom socket may well be good enough for your situation.

I'm assuming here that if session 0 doesn't exist that it will be created.